# How can I use `I()` with `paste0`?

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes and I would like to evaluate (multiple) different models on each. MWE

```
df1 <- data.frame(A3 = c(-5, 5, 1), 
                  B3 = c(0, 10, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(A4 = c(5, 15, 1))
                  B4 = c(10, 20, 1))

myfun <- function(arg1, arg2){ # arg1 =1 or 2
  if (arg2 == 1){
    eqn <- paste0("A", arg1+2) ~ paste0("B", arg1+2) + I(as.name(paste0("B", arg1+2))^2)
  } else {
    eqn <- paste0("A", arg1+2) ~ paste0("B", arg1+2) + I(as.name(paste0("B", arg1+2))^2) +I(as.name(paste0("B", arg1+2))^3)
  }
 
  return (lm(formula = eqn, data = eval(as.name(paste0("df", arg1)))
    )
  )
}
```

For example if I run `myfun(1,2)` I would like to get `lm(A4 ~ B4 + I(B4^2) + I(B4^3), data = df2)`. But whatever I try I get the following error message `Error in (paste0("B", arg1 +2))^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. From what I read in `?I`, I imagine this is because R isolates whatever is passed into `I()`, so it doesn't realize I am trying to transform a variable: is that what is going on, and is it something I can fix? Also, is there a better way to estimate multiple models quickly? All the similar questions I found used the same `data.frame` across models, while I have to account for the response (and predictor) variables coming from different dataframes for different models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

The issue is that your are doing a math operation on a string, i.e with `(paste0("B", arg1 +2))^2` you try to square a string, that's why you get the error. Inytead you can simply glue you formula together as a string an d converted it to a formula via `as.formula`:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(A3 = c(-5, 5, 1), 
                  B3 = c(0, 10, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(A4 = c(5, 15, 1))
B4 = c(10, 20, 1)

myfun <- function(arg1, arg2){ # arg1 =1 or 2
  if (arg2 == 1){
    eqn <- paste0("A", arg1+2, " ~ B", arg1+2," + I(B", arg1+2, "^2)")
  } else {
    eqn <- paste0("A", arg1+2, " ~ B", arg1+2," + I(B", arg1+2, "^2) + I(B", arg1+2, "^3)")
  }
  
  return (lm(formula = as.formula(eqn), data = eval(as.name(paste0("df", arg1)))
  )
  )
}

myfun(2, 1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = as.formula(eqn), data = eval(as.name(paste0("df", 
#>     arg1))))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           B4      I(B4^2)  
#>     0.84795      0.12281      0.02924
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to construct the `formula` with `glue`

```
myfun <- function(arg1, arg2){ 
    eqn <- switch(arg2, 
                 `1` = glue::glue("A{arg1 + 2}~ B{arg1+2} + I(B{arg1+2}^2)"),
      
                 glue::glue("A{arg1 + 2}~ B{arg1+2}", 
                                     "+ I(B{arg1+2}^2) + I(B{arg1+2}^3)")
       )
    model <- lm(eqn, data = get(paste0('df', arg1), envir = .GlobalEnv))
    model$call <- as.formula(eqn)
    return(model)

      
    }
      
myfun(2, 1)
#Call:
#A4 ~ B4 + I(B4^2)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           B4      I(B4^2)  
#    0.84795      0.12281      0.02924
```